# Calling an ASPX method from an ASCX control

Tags: asp.net

I have a method HasAdminRole() on home.aspx that I call from an ASCX control. And the ASCX works using (Home)this.Page).HasAdminRole() with the user control on home.aspx

Now, when I add that same ASCX to a different ASPX page Adminuser.aspx, I get an error when the ASCX tries to call (Home)this.Page).HasAdminRole() from a different ASPX page than when on home.aspx

I get the error Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.adminuser_aspx' to type 'CALE.Home'.

How do I resolve this when using the same ASCX on multiple ASPX's and the user control tries to call the single method on Home.aspx

Comment: Move the method to the control instead? Or make a base Page class that all the pages derive from that the control can then expect to find?

Comment: That works for a method. But, I also have to access a button event on the aspx. If the user decides to go to a different page I call a button_click method on that page from within the ascx.                                                             if (Menu1.SelectedValue == "showestimateportfolio")
                ((Home)this.Page).btnEstPortfolio_Click(sender, e);  This works when Im on Home.aspx but i get the cast error when on any other aspx page.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest moving your admin/roles logic out from your .aspx and into a class that's accessible from both your .aspx and .ascx. It's a bit of 'separation of concerns' and a bit of tidiness in having the logic in common areas. Basically -- only keep page related logic in your page code-behind.

```
public static class Roles
{
    public static HasAdminRole(User someUser)
    {
       // implementation
    }
}
```

Call it from any page's code-behind or other helper class:

```
 User foo;
 bool isAdmin = Roles.HasAdminRole(foo);
```

Comment: That works for a method. But, I also have to access a button event on the aspx. If the user decides to go to a different page I call a button_click method on that page from within the ascx. if (Menu1.SelectedValue == "showestimateportfolio") ((Home)this.Page).btnEstPortfolio_Click(sender, e); This works when Im on Home.aspx but i get the cast error when on any other aspx page

Answer (score 0):

So I just figured out a solution to this problem.

You can create a client side trigger in the aspx page and call it with javascript from your ascx page.

e.g.

aspx page:

```
<script>
 function doSomething()
 {
    //set hidden field values or do whatever else you might need to do here
    $('#<%= btnDoSomething.ClientID%>').click();
 }
</script>

 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDoSomething" OnClick="btnDoSomething_Click" CssClass="hidden" />
```

aspx code behind:

```
protected void btnDoSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do whatever you need to on the aspx page
        }
```

Now you can call that javascript function from any ascx page that you like.

e.g. 
ascx page:

```
<button type="button" onclick="doSomething()">do something on your aspx page<button/>
```